# flutter : How to change error position in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using form and TextFormField to get data from user :

```
child: TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  enabled: item.editable,
  autofocus: false,
  maxLines: 1,
  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
  controller: TextEditingController()
    ..text = item.value == null
        ? ""
        : replaceFarsiNumber(
            item.value.substring(3, 5)),
  validator: (val) {
    if (val.length < 2) {
      return "دورقمی وارد کنید";
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (_) => _form.currentState.validate(),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "دقیقه",
    labelStyle:
        TextStyle(color: color_raisedButton_active),
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: color_raisedButton_active,
          width: 1.0),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: color_raisedButton_active,
          width: 1.0),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: color_raisedButton_active,
          width: 1.0),
    ),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide:
          BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.0),
    ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 5.0,
        top: 0.0,
        right: 5.0,
        bottom: 0.0),
  ),
),
```

I add a validator to count number of word that user added to TextFormField. under some situation i want to show error like this to user:

[image]

How can i change the error label position to **below** of **TextFormField**